# THREE.js OrbitControls lagging?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I'm making a solar system in three.js and experiencing some lag with OrbitControls. The website is [solarsim.github.io](http://solarsim.github.io.) The rest of the program runs fine while the controls are lagging (i.e. the planets are updating and orbiting), what is wrong here?

Comment: I didn't notice any lag. If by lag you mean that sometimes, when you try to drag, it keeps pointing at something else, that's not lag. That's your positioning of the camera moving it back, not lag

Comment: I do not see any lag either. But you are calling `OrbitControls.update()` in the render loop, and that is normally not required in your use case with r.71. Also, you are modifying the camera properties behind the back of the controls, which is not recommended.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks! It only lags sometimes and I can't seem to recreate it when I want to. It could just be my machine / browser. Also, can you elaborate on modifying the camera's properties behind the back of the controls?

Comment: You have given the controls responsibility for setting the camera properties, but you modify the camera properties yourself in the render loop. Make sure you understand the `OrbitControls` code.